# Recurrence $A_{n+1}=A_{n}+\mathbf{E}G_n$

Tags: recurrence-relations

This looks like a straightforward recurrence, but I have an impression I made a mistake somewhere. In this equation $G_n$ is a random variable

$
G_n=\left\{
\begin{array}{c c}
0 & 1-p_n \\
a_n & p_n \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

Obviously $\mathbf{E}G_n=a_n p_n$ and border condition is $A_1=1$. So the obvious solution to the problem seems to be

$
A_{n+1}=1+\sum_{j=2}^{n}a_j p_j
$

I find this solution way too simple. Do I have to use a generating function somewhere? I had [this](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/1009/1009.1031v2.pdf) article in mind when thinking of this problem.

Comment: You should be summing from $j=1$, as $A_2 = A_1 + \mathbb{E}(G_1) = 1 + a_1 p_1$.

Comment: I really fail to see what it is you are asking here ?

Comment: Apart from a typo in the index of summation, the calculation in the post is fine. The answer *is* simple, there is no need to complicate it. There are enough hard problems.